# Django: KeyError at /panel/home/login/ 'HTTP_REFERER'

Tags: django, redirect, django-rest-framework, django-views, http-referer

I have a problem to get the HTTP_REFERER address from django.
I want to userauth system in two separate login pages and for that, I set in one of login pages if the url that redirected person to this login page had 'business' word, redirect user into business login page.
Thanks for Help

I wrote this Code:

```py
if 'business' in request.META['HTTP_REFERER']:
return redirect('panel_business:login_business')
```

Here is My Error:
`KeyError at /panel/home/login/  'HTTP_REFERER'`

Django Error Full Trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8009/panel/home/login/?next=/panel/business/

Django Version: 4.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'website',
 'panel',
 'panel_business']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arshia/w/recycle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/arshia/w/recycle/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/arshia/w/recycle/panel/views.py", line 44, in login_home
    if 'business' in request.META['HTTP_REFERER']:

Exception Type: KeyError at /panel/home/login/
Exception Value: 'HTTP_REFERER'
```

Comment: The `HTTP_REFERER` is not always provided in the `request.META`.

Comment: It is what the browser provides, but as the HTTP specs say: trust the request data, but validate. Certain browsers, mainly the ones focussed on privacy, don't send the HTTP_REFERER header.

Comment: Then How can I get previous URL?

Comment: you don't, or at least there is no reliable way. To some extent, you could use middleware to register it with the session id, but again, not all browsers consistenlty send the session id.

Comment: How can I handle two login urls in one django project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a simple way :)

```py
@login_required(login_url='your login url')
def your_page(request):
    # something ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use

```
if 'business' in request.build_absolute_uri():
```

or

```
if 'business' in request.path
```

also if you mean 'business' in next =
you can try

```
next = request.GET.get('next')
```